# uitableviewcell disappears after rotating iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I am facing problem for `UITableViewCell`

What I am doing,
Having three table views on 3 different views of same view controller of iPad.

Among which,
on 1st tableview I have cell with content view button and text.
Text+button is showing well when the app loads first time.

But as soon as I rotate the device the button+text disappears.

What I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

```
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                     reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
}

if (tableView.tag == 1005)
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        // Make a circular shape
        circularPath=[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35)    cornerRadius:MAX(35, 35)];
        circle.path = circularPath.CGPath;
        // Configure the apperence of the circle
        circle.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        circle.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        circle.lineWidth = 0;

        UIButton* cameraBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 35,35)];
        cameraBtn.backgroundcolor = [UIColor redColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview: cameraBtn];
        cameraBtn.layer.mask=circle;

        UILabel *photoLbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 150, 30)];
        photoLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        photoLbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:16];
        photoLbl.text = @"Take photo";
        [cell.contentView addSubview:photoLbl];
        [photoLbl release];
        [cameraBtn release];
        cell.contentView.frame = cell.bounds;
        cell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    }   

    return cell;
}
```

I searched for all links on SO, but didn't get suitable solution.

Comment: use custom UITableViewCell instead of using default UITableViewCell. In custom tableView cell set the frame of the button and textfield for both the orientation that way it will work.

Comment: You shouldn't be changing `cell.contentView.frame` and `cell.autoresizingMask`

Comment: Hi @Khanh, I tried that way too... but didn't worked.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code. If you are using xcode 6 plz check if you have sizing class enabled in storyboard. Try disabling it.

Comment: Hi Ashish, thanks. but there is no single xib used in code. all the code is done programatically.
I found the solution, at the time of rotating, my base view was getting called but not the table view. so I set the tag for tableview and reloads it after rotation
thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upgrading your simulator ,  I had the same problem and it worked fine when I tested it in a real device.